# How to include some commands depending on the version

Tags: conditionals, latex-misc

Two versions of Latex or actually texlive need to edit one document. The older one does not know `microtype` etc. How can I conditionally include text and commands for one version or the other?

`\fmtversion` is 2011/06/27 and 2021/11/15 (which I installed on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with `sudo apt install texlive-full` some days ago)

Comment: `microtype` is not new. 2011 shouldn't be a problem. If it is, the issue isn't the age of your TeX Live, but something else. (Maybe partial installation or smaller scheme; maybe issue with finding files ....)

Comment: In any case, the old version cannot upgrade (Ubuntu 14). And with the new version, I had to say `texlive-full` before it was present.

Comment: So just set a boolean (if) somewhere or you can test for version or for file existence. It depends on your setup which you prefer. You've not provided any code to help people help.

Comment: Testing for the `fmtversion` is not possible?

Comment: As to the setup: Preferably, everything is within the same .tex-file. Nothing else.

Comment: It's possible, but it won't tell you whether `microtype` is installed. Testing for the package's existence will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing `\fmtversion` tells you the version of the LaTeX kernel, but nothing about the available packages. If you need to check the existence of a package, you can look for the file that provides it

```latex
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}
  {%
    % Code where you can find microtype, probably including
    \usepackage{microtype}%
  }
  {%
    % Code where you cannot find microtype
  }%
```

Comment: So much  better! No more toolchain needed